# Checking the hardware info of test system via Windbg

Tags: windbg

Is there any Windbg command that tells about the installed hardware on the test machine. Need to know the amount of RAM installed on the test machine.

Comment: In kernel debugging or user mode debugging?

Comment: @Thomas: Kernel Mode Debugging

Comment: !vm 0x21 can tell you the physical memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kernel mode debugging, `!sysinfo` should help.

In user mode, physical RAM is usually not interesting, since the program works on virtual memory instead. So, from a crash dump, this information is definitely not available, it could only be available on a live system.

If you have access to a shell during live system debugging, you can use:

```
.shell -i- wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed
```

Note that this will give incorrect information when doing post mortem debugging (dump analysis).

```
0:000> .shell -i- wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed
BankLabel  Capacity    MemoryType  Speed  TypeDetail  
BANK 2     8589934592  0           1600   128         
BANK 0     8589934592  0           1600   128         

.shell: Process exited
```

Answer (score 2):

There's `!sysinfo smbios -memory -csv` but that is only available during kernel debugging or a kernel dump.

If all you have is a userdump, there's no way I know of to get that information but that raises the question why you think you need it?